# Handshake error while running flutter pub upgrade command

Tags: flutter, dart

Handshake error while running flutter pub upgrade command.

Running pub upgrade...

> Handshake error in client (OS Error:
> CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(../../third_party/boringssl/src/ssl/handshake.c c:359))

Could someone help me on fixing this ?

Comment: Well, " We don't recommend that third parties depend upon it. Doing so is likely to be frustrating because there are no guarantees of API or ABI stability." This is what I read from their readme. So what is the purpose of it?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a [letsencrypt and dart http issue](https://issueexplorer.com/issue/flutter/flutter/91367), it is caused by lower versions of Android not having the X1 certificate, Android thinks the certificate is selfsigned.
More details:
https://www.catchpoint.com/blog/lessons-from-an-internet-outage-issues-caused-by-lets-encrypt-dst-root-ca-x3-expiration

There are a number of solutions out there; You can explore them from [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/http/issues/627).

download isrgrootx1.pem

in main.dart

```
final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/certificates/isrgrootx1.pem');
HttpOverrides.global = CustomHttpOverrides(data);
runApp(...)
```

in CustomHttpOverrides.dart

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

class CustomHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  ByteData data;
  CustomHttpOverrides(this.data);

  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
    final SecurityContext clientContext = SecurityContext()..setTrustedCertificatesBytes(data.buffer.asUint8List());
    return super.createHttpClient(clientContext);
  }
}
```